# Protege plugin with manipulate data

Tags: java, protege

I am trying to create a plugin for protege which will manipulate some date from it and do something with them, but when I try to write in a file some records, they do not work and i do not understand why, I will put the code here maybe someone knows. If I click on the button it shows me that I have 100 classes in active ontology but it does not write in the file where I execute the same piece of code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(
            "Get Data from ontology .\n");
    message.append("The active ontology has ");
    message.append(getOWLModelManager().getActiveOntology().getClassesInSignature().size());
    String filename = "C:\\Users\\Onu\\Documents\\GitHub\\protege-plugin-examples\\target\\file.txt";
    int records = getOWLModelManager().getActiveOntology().getClassesInSignature().size();
    try {
        BufferedWriter reader = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        reader.write(records);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", filename);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    message.append(" classes.");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getOWLWorkspace(), message.toString());   
}
```

Comment: Does not work doesn't help people provide answers. You need to say why it didn't work. Did it no do as you expect, did it produce as error, something else..?

Comment: If i write in console records , it`s shows me that it`s 100 . If i try to write in the file , does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the buffered writer after writing, or the program might terminate without saving all data.